# Can't make the AngularJS router work

Tags: angularjs

I am new using AngularJS, i am trying to implement a router to manage 2 different views.

I have followed the [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) but i get an error on my javascript console:

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7-build.2029+sha.80e7a45/$injector/modulerr…Flocalhost%3A3094%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A188)`

This error only happens when i add the `APP.config()` part of the code.

I can reach the route /views/a.html directly on my browser, and i do have a `<div ng-view></div>` in my html code (index.html), i don't understand what i am missing...

```
var APP = angular.module('APP', [ 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularFileUpload', 'ngRoute' ])
            //Load Facebook SDK & co...
});

APP.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/a', {
                templateUrl: 'views/a.html',
                controller: 'aCtrl'
            }).
            when('/b', {
                templateUrl: 'views/b.html',
                controller: 'bCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/a'
            });
    }
]);

APP.controller('aCtrl', function() {
    console.log('CALL A CONTROLLER');
});

APP.controller('bCtrl', function() {
    console.log('CALL B CONTROLLER');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject `ngRoute` into your app:

```
angular.module('ngViewExample', ['ngRoute'])
```

Unfortunately the demo app is still using v1.0.6 so you're going to see a lot of inconsistencies. Here's a better example from the documentation:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route)